# pegar valor de um elementbyid.innerhtml fazer calculo e colocar no html

Tags: javascript, html

Opa, então... eu tenho um valor de um input type range que está sendo jogado em um span quero pegar o valor desse span com o javascript, fazer um calculo com esse numero do span e colocar em outro span.

codigo do js:

```
 var parcela = document.getElementById('exibePercent').value;
 var parcela1 = 4;
 var result1 = parcela / parcela1;
 document.getElementById("parcela1").value = result1;
```

html:

```
<span id="exibePercent">1000</span> <!----  SPAN QUE QUERO PEGAR O VALOR E JOGAR NO OUTRO SPAN----> 
<span id="parcela1" value=""></span> <!----- SPAN QUE QUERO QUE RETORNE O VALOR DO RESULT DO JS ---->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter o valor de uma `span`, você não deve utilizar o a propriedade `value`, mas sim a `innerHTML`. Tanto para obter o valor quanto para trocar o mesmo.

```js
function trocarValorSpan() {
  var parcela = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('exibePercent').innerHTML);
  var parcela1 = 4;
  var result1 = parcela / parcela1;
  document.getElementById("parcela1").innerHTML = result1;
}
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}

button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span id="exibePercent">1000</span> <!----  SPAN QUE QUERO PEGAR O VALOR E JOGAR NO OUTRO SPAN----> 
<span id="parcela1" value=""></span> <!----- SPAN QUE QUERO QUE RETORNE O VALOR DO RESULT DO JS ---->

<button onclick="trocarValorSpan()">Trocar valor da span</button>
```

---

```js
var parcela = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('exibePercent').innerHTML);
var parcela1 = 4;
var result1 = parcela / parcela1;
document.getElementById("parcela1").innerHTML = result1;
```

```html
<span id="exibePercent">1000</span> <!----  SPAN QUE QUERO PEGAR O VALOR E JOGAR NO OUTRO SPAN----> 
<span id="parcela1" value=""></span> <!----- SPAN QUE QUERO QUE RETORNE O VALOR DO RESULT DO JS ---->
```

> Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Preciso que o valor do novo span seja exibido automaticamente, sem button, como posso fazer?

Comment: Basta deixar o código "solto" e não dentro de uma função, vou criar outro exemplo pra você ver.

Comment: Outra duvida que tenho é que o span "exibir" é dinâmico, sempre troca de valor, então o novo span também tem que ser dinâmico

Comment: Não sei exatamente o que você quer fazer, mas se deseja que o valor fique trocando, pode utilizar a função ```setInterval```, se o valor deve mudar quando alguma "outra coisa" mudar, talvez seja possível usar o evento ```onchange```.

Comment: Eu tenho um input do tipo range, é um simulador de empréstimo. O usuário define o valor do seu empréstimo que é jogado para o span exibePercent, daí com esse valor do input, quero definir o valor das parcelas, dinamicamente.

Comment: Então dá pra fazer utilizando ```onchange```, basta criar uma função com o JS da resposta e colocar no ```onchange``` onde o usuário informar o valor.

Comment: Consegui, obrigado.